# Some columns in one table style and some columns in another table style

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given a table, we could choose one table style for it.

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to apply one table style to some columns (e.g., Column P) of the table and another table style to some columns (e.g., Column Q) of the table?

Comment: It wouldn't be called "table style" in this case ...

Comment: You could fill the columns with color you need.